# Cheating cohen before a get

Tags: kohen-priest

If a Cohen cheats on his wife and has sexual encounters with other women beside his wife before giving a get, is he still permitted to duchen and perform duties?

Comment: Obviously this theoretical kohen has done some not-okay stuff ... but our focus on what they can do in shul tends to be on the continued, publicly-visible behavior...

Comment: "Perform duties" -- as in get the first aliyah? Pidyon HaBen? Or do you want to know about theory's sake in the Bais HaMikdash?

Comment: They are still a kohen, warts and all...

Answer (score 7):

The [Shulchan Aruch](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.128.39?lang=bi) (O.C.128:39) does not include this on its list of disqualifications, and then goes on to add:

"If he does not have any of the disqualifying factors for the priestly blessing, even if he is not careful with mitzvot and the entire congregation complains about him, he may perform the priestly blessing."

The Rema there: "Because other sins do not prevent him from performing the priestly blessing."

[Halachipedia](https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Birkat_Cohanim#Things_that_may_prevent_a_Cohen_from_doing_Birkat_Cohanim) does not include these as grounds for disqualifying a Kohain from performing Birkhat Cohenim or recieving the Kohain aliyah to the Torah. Further, former Sephardic Chief Rabbi Ovadiah Yosef allows even a Kohain who is publicly mechalel Shabbat and publicly eats non-Kosher to do so as well (Yabia Omer volume 7, 15).

[Rabbi Melamed in Pnenei Halacha](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/03-20-14/) disallows a Kohain who publicly breaks Shabbat but does not mention private misconduct beyond marrying a woman forbidden to him.

Finally, worth mentioning- a Kohain is required d'orayta to go up and give the Birkhat Cohenim when called to do so, while the conduct you describe is forbidden derabanan (according to most opinions.) In theory one can always ask the Kohain to leave the room before "Retzeh Hashem" to avoid such a conundrum.

In practice, of course, one would have to consult a rabbi if chas v'shalom such a scenario were to actually occur.

Comment: Right. There's a line between "he's clearly, publicly married to someone prohibited" and whatever private infractions he's done. The Gemara's example of disqualifying someone from the battlefield is of the public, visible variety -- they're married to someone prohibited.